# Connecting oracle from c++ .. MSVCR90.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: oracle10g

I am trying to connect to oracle database from c++ using OCCI, I am following [these instructions from Mark Williams](http://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/07/getting-started-with-occi-windows.html), But when I run my program it gives error as ***MSVCR90.dll is missing from your computer***. I suppose its problem related to vc compiler maybe its trying to use vc10 and oracle dll searches for vc9 dll? The oracle version I am trying to connect to is 10g.

Is it possible to configure VS2010 to use VC9 instead of VC10?

*I am using Visual Studio 2010 under Windows 7.*

Comment: you might want to tag this as vc++ or visual studio and windows in addition to oracle10g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the client application requires a different version of the MSVC runtime from what is installed on your computer. Msvcr90.dll is the Common Runtime library for Microsoft Visual C++ 2008. You will need to install this. (Note that for this version, it is no longer considered a shared system directory, so it installs as a Windows side-by-side assembly.)

You can install it by downloading the installers [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en) or [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=A5C84275-3B97-4AB7-A40D-3802B2AF5FC2&displaylang=en):